# Compile an 'if' in a "for" at the same line

Tags: python

Just for curiosity and knowledge, of course.
Do you have any suggestion to compile these two lines in a single line?

What I have now:

```
for files in os.listdir(path):
    if files.endswith("geneclusters.txt"):
```

What I am trying to obtain:

```
for (files in os.listdir(path)) if files.endswith("geneclusters.txt"):
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok. I will remove the question.

Comment: it depends what you wanna do *next*

Comment: Depending on what you want to do after if, you could use list comprehension

Comment: There is something called list comprehension that creates a list in a single line with the ability to add a filtering, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: To open the specific files in 'endswith'

Comment: You just want to **open** the file and do nothing?

Comment: You can use `list comprehension` here `[ to_do for files in os.listdir(path) if files.endswith("geneclusters.txt")` depending what you want to do next

Comment: Folks, at least suggest a *generator* expression, not a *list* comprehension. The memory allocation of later is a complete waste in such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot merge an `if` statement into a `for` statement. However, you can use a generator *expression* inside a `for` statement.

```
#            V --- generator expression ---------------------------------------------- V
for files in (files for files in os.listdir(path) if files.endswith("geneclusters.txt")):
    ...
```

Note that there is no performance advantage, and in fact this is usually slower. On top, it is generally less readable.

Do *not* use a list comprehension, delimited by `[]` instead of `()`, for such use cases. It creates the entire intermediate list in memory.

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis on the end of this, but I can't edit due to character limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
for files in [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith("geneclusters.txt")]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course (using list comprehension), depending on what you want to do next:

```
for file in [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith("geneclusters.txt")]:
```